# How to set up a progress bar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a php page named import.php. while executing this file  a lot of database operation is doing.So i need to show the progress to the user, by  using a progres bar.How is it possible using  any of these php ajax, javascript, jquery,css, flash... methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial on it:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-progress-bar-with-javascript/

**[and the demo](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/266_progressSlider/jQuery%20UI/regForm.html)**

**[Here is the php implementation too.](http://www.silverspider.com/2005/php-progress-bar/)**